# How to make the activity authentification appear just after the animation (splash screen) of the logo.please help me

Tags: java, android, xml

$I made for the first time an application so my problem is to make the layout login appear in the same activity 'splashscreen' after the animation 
this my code for splashscreen.java
 Where could the problem be?

```
public class Splashscreen extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    Spinner spinner;
    Button btnCnx;
    LinearLayout ln;
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    }
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Thread splashTread;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
      //  btnCnx = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Connexion);
       // btnCnx.setCursorVisible(false);
        //**************************************************************
        ln = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinLaySpalScrenLogin);
        ln.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        StartAnimations();
        Button Key_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Connexion);
        //Key_save.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Key_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("DEMO TAG", "CLick on sign in button");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Splashscreen.this, calendrier.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
//        ********************************************************
        // Spinner element
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.fonction);
        // Spinner click listener
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        // Spinner Drop down elements
        List<String> fonction = new ArrayList<String>();
        fonction.add("Administrateur");
        fonction.add("Agent laboratoire");
        fonction.add("Chef releve");
        fonction.add("Releveur");
        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, fonction);
        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
//        Key_save.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // On selecting a spinner item
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        // Showing selected spinner item
      //  Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Vous avez choisit: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    private void StartAnimations() {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
        anim.reset();
        LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
        l.clearAnimation();
        l.startAnimation(anim);
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
        anim.reset();
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash);
        iv.clearAnimation();
        iv.startAnimation(anim);
        ln.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        splashTread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int waited = 0;
                    // Splash screen pause time
                    while (waited < 3500) {
                        sleep(100);
                        waited += 100;
                    }

                    //Intent intent = new Intent(Splashscreen.this,
                      //      saisieIndex.class);
                    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    //startActivity(intent);
                    //Splashscreen.this.finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // do nothing
                }
//                finally {
//                    //Splashscreen.this.finish();
//                }
            ln.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        };
        splashTread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: re-check your post. Not possible to read a single thing.
Use Ctrl+K to put your code.
Also properly indent and separate your code in new lines.

Comment: OK, thnx this my first time :)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to create either an activity that loads right after the `Splash Screen` i.e. `Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext, Authenticate.class);` then `startActivity(i)`. Once that loads you can use `getSharedPreferences` to get a list of users registered on the device, or you can pull the user list from an online source. From this point you can set a `boolean success` meaning the username and password match, which in that case you would start the `Mainactivity` using the same code above. If not you can let them know via `toast`, changing a `textView`, etc.

Comment: Sorry I mean that the layout activity appear in the same activity of screenSplash Like SKYPE just after the animation

Comment: In that case you can probably accomplish this by creating a fragment that is `centerInParent` and only appears if the user isn't already logged in/`onCreate` in the parent activity

Comment: the 'Linearlayout' is logged in 'onCreate' I use it 'ln = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinLaySpalScrenLogin);' and this line '        ln.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);' before    'StartAnimations();' and i want to use ' ln.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);' to make the layout authentification appear after the screensplash logo animation :(

Comment: So you probably want to put a timer on the animation after `onCreate` has completed. You can find a simple timer script anywhere online